# Choosing between MANCOVA and RDA to factor out treatment effects

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, biostatistics, manova

I am working on a data set of intertidal organisms and am looking for a multivariate technique that will help me determine why some groups have different species assemblages than others. I was thinking multivariate analysis of covariance (MANCOVA) might be a good method because it takes care of the experimental design (which is 12 experimental blocks, 3 treatments and all 36 sites being sampled once a year for 15 years), the raw data, and covariates (which will hopefully include data about water temperatures, salinity, etc). However, it seems like perhaps people use MANCOVA more to factor OUT the covariates to focus on the experimental design, whereas I really am more interested in doing the opposite (factoring out the effect of the treatments). This is because the interesting stuff we're noticing happened in spite of the treatments - we think because of unexpected climate stuff.

Is this an appropriate method to use for my purposes or not? I already have a principal component analysis (PCA) that gives a visual representation of some of the dominant assemblages, and am thinking if MANCOVA won't work my next best bet might be doing a redundancy analysis (RDA) instead.